# Check for Existence of a Result in Linq-to-xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm using Linq-to-XML to do a simple "is this user registered" check (no security here, just making a list of registered users for a desktop app). How do I handle the result from a query like this:

```
var people = from person in currentDoc.Descendants("Users")
                     where (string)person.Element("User") == searchBox.Text
                     select person;
```

I understand the most common way to use the result would be something like

```
foreach (var line in people){
    //do something here
}
```

but what do you do if `person` comes back empty, which is what would happen if the person isn't registered?

I've looked around on this site and on MSDN and haven't found a really clear answer yet.

Extra credit: Give a good explanation of what `people` contains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read that it's better to use Any() rather than Count()==0 in these situations.  E.g

```
bool anyPeople = people.Any();
if (anyPeople) {
```

See http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/07/ienumerablecount-is-code-smell.html for more discussion on the performance impact of using Count() with Linq, especially with IEnumerable, where the entire collection is iterated by the Count() method.

Also using Any() arguably is a clearer explanation of your intent that Count()

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
from person in currentDoc.Descendants("Users")
where (string)person.Element("User") == searchBox.Text && !person.IsEmpty
select person;
```

The above will select only non-empty person elements.  There is also a `HasElements` property that says whether or not it has any child elements - this may be better to use depending on your XML structure, as blank space make make `IsEmpty` return false (blank space can count as text).

The `people` variable is going to be an `IEnumerable<XElement>` variable, as you appear to be querying a collection of `XElement`.  The var keyword is simply a shortcut to allow it the variable to be typed by the compiler, so you didn't need to figure out the type beforehand and use `List<XElement> people = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a people.Count() and if you get 0, you know that person is not registered.

Comment: I seem to remember a blog post advising against this: http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/07/ienumerablecount-is-code-smell.html as for IEnumberable, it iterates through all items in the collection.  With databases, the performance is better, but still the SQL generated isn't optimal

Answer (score 0):

As told by Matt use `Count()==0` or `Any()`.

people is `IEnumerable<XElement>` I think.