# Interview Question: .Any() vs if (.Length > 0) for testing if a collection has elements

Tags: c#, linq, collections

In a recent interview I was asked what the difference between `.Any()` and `.Length > 0` was and why I would use either when testing to see if a collection had elements.

This threw me a little as it seems a little obvious but feel I may be missing something.

I suggested that you use `.Length` when you simply need to know that a collection has elements and `.Any()` when you wish to filter the results.

Presumably `.Any()` takes a performance hit too as it has to do a loop / query internally.

Comment: Just curious, was `.Count()` an option?  It'll use `.Length` (actually `.Count` from the `ICollection` interface) if available, and enumerate if not...`.Any()` doesn't have a shortcut like this.

Comment: I always assumed that native properties are pre-calculated if they are available such as `.length` for array and `.count` for collection. Therefore I would use `.any()` only if hey are not available or I want to to a conditional `.any(lambda)` check.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Length` only exists for some collection types such as `Array`.

`Any` is an extension method that can be used with any collection that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

If `Length` is present then you can use it, otherwise use `Any`.

---

> Presumably .Any() takes a performance hit too as it has to do a loop / query internally.

`Enumerable.Any` does not loop. It fetches an iterator and checks if `MoveNext` returns true. Here is the source code from [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There's also an `IQueryable<T>` version, but I'm not which which the OP is talking about, maybe both.  Edit: by collection I'm guessing you're right, just linq-to-entities

Answer (score 14):

I'm guessing the interviewer may have meant to ask about checking `Any()` versus `Count() > 0` (as opposed to `Length > 0`).

Basically, here's the deal.

`Any()` will effectively try to determine if a collection has any members by enumerating over a single item. (There is an overload to check for a given criterion using a `Func<T, bool>`, but I'm guessing the interviewer was referring to the version of `Any()` that takes no arguments.) This makes it O(1).

`Count()` will check for a `Length` or `Count` property (from a `T[]` or an `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`) first. This would generally be O(1). If that isn't available, however, it will count the items in a collection by enumerating over the entire thing. This would be O(n).

A `Count` or `Length` *property*, if available, would most likely be O(1) just like `Any()`, and would probably perform better as it would require no enumerating at all. But the `Count()` *extension method* does not ensure this. Therefore it is sometimes O(1), sometimes O(n).

Presumably, if you're dealing with a nondescript `IEnumerable<T>` and you don't know whether it implements `ICollection<T>` or not, **you are much better off using `Any()` than `Count() > 0` if your intention is simply to ensure the collection is not empty**.

Comment: I approve using Any() but it is reasonable to use Count or Length for arrays/collection because it can be easily understood by new hires that came from another framework.

Answer (score 1):

`Length` is a property of array types, while `Any()` is an extension method of `Enumerable`. Therefore, you can use Length only when working with arrays. When working with more abstract types (`IEnumerable<T>`), you can use Any().

Answer (score 1):

.Length... System.Array
.Any   ... IEnumerable (extension method).

I would prefer using "length" whenever i can find it. Property is anyhow light-weight than any method call.

Though, implementation of "Any" won't be doing anything more than the  below mentioned code.

```
 private static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            return items!=null && items.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
        }
```

Also,
A better question could have been a difference beterrn ".Count" and ".Length", what say :).

Comment: Interesting... can you explain : "Property is anyhow light-weight than any method call. "

Comment: @David: Property is generally a get/set over a field (an in-memory value) while a method has freedom to perform all possible computations. I would always rely on a call to a get_Property than a method call. ( eg: obj.ComputedValue Vs ComputeValue() )

Comment: So it is merely the convention or guidelines, not any technical reason.  A property could be implemented in violation of the convention (for example, the property could call the method).

Comment: why this check, items!=null because the call will anyways fail if the items is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more general question of what to choose if we have 2 way to express something.
In does situation I would suggest the statement: "Be specific" quote from Peter Norvig in his book PAIP

Be specific mean use what best describe what your are doing.
Thus what you want to say is something like:

```
collection.isEmpty()
```

If you don't have such construct I will choose the common idiom that the communities used.
For me `.Length > 0` is not the best one since it impose that you can size the object.
Suppose your implement infinite list. `.Lenght` would obviously not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds quite similar to this Stackoverflow question about difference between .Count and .Any for checking for existence of a result: [Check for Existence of a Result in Linq-to-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540220/check-for-existence-of-a-result-in-linq-to-xml/2540302#2540302)

In that case it is better to use Any then Count, as Count will iterate all elements of an IEnumerable

Comment: This is not true, `.Count()` **will** use the `.Count` (which gets `.Length` on an Array for example) property on an `ICollection` (generic or not), `.Any()` **won't** use this and will enumerate, you can fire up reflector to see this, still true in .Net 4.  An `IQueryable<T>` is a different story, but on `IEnumerable<T>` this doesn't change.

Comment: That's interesting - I'd interpreted the following as being that Count will enumerate and and Any will not: http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/07/ienumerablecount-is-code-smell.html

Comment: @Nick: `Any()` (at least the overload that takes no arguments) will enumerate over *one* item. `Count()`, if the underlying `IEnumerable<T>` is not an `ICollection<T>`, will enumerate over *all* items. For this reason it makes much more sense to use `Any()` than `Count() > 0` if the collection type is not known.

Comment: @Dan - That's not absolute though, opening an iterator itself may be very expensive, so checking `.Count` vs getting the iterator and grabbing ons is an unknown cost difference.  In any case, for the purposes of an interview, won't you know which collection you're dealing with *most* of the time? If it's `ICollection` every time and you use `.Any()` it's more expensive.  I think your qualifier of "if the collection type is not known" is the key here, unless you're writing a framework for others, I think you *do* know this most of the time.

Comment: @Nick: I think the "unless you're writing a framework for others" part makes this possibility sound rarer than it is. You might be writing a general-purpose method or library; it doesn't have to be an entire framework. That said, you're right that the cost of opening an iterator is unknown; but so is the cost of accessing the `Count` property of some 3rd party `ICollection<T>`. There are always going to be unknowns; in the case of an `IEnumerable<T>` of unknown type, to *me*, `Any()` seems like a much better educated guess.

Comment: @Nick: Anyway, it seems to me the whole point of an interview question like this would be to distinguish whether the developer understood that `Count()` could potentially be an O(n) operation (though the OP did say `Length`...). Clearly, as long as he/she demonstrated understanding of these matters, the interviewer ought to have been satisfied.

Comment: @Dan - All good points, most of what I write is for my own or local consumption so the unknown type is comparatively rare, I see how that's easily not the case though.  I *definitely* agree on the interviewer piece, him knowing the difference and possible costs of each approach *should* be the entire point...unfortunately for me, a lot of programmers we've interviewed lately don't have a clue :-/

Answer (score 0):

We know that .Length is only used for Arrays and .Any() is used for collections of IEnumerable.

You can swap .Count for .Length and you have the same question for working with collections of IEnumberable

Both .Any() and .Count perform a null check before beginning an enumerator. So with regards to performance they are the same.

As for the array lets assume we have the following line:

```
int[] foo = new int[10];
```

Here foo.Length is 10. While this is correct it may not be the answer your looking for because we haven't added anything to the array yet. If foo is null it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

What for an discussion. All source code is available and so you know that:
If you are using instances which have the property Length or Count then you have always O(1). The value is a member of your instance and you can directly compare against any other value. It is only a compare operation between two values.

The extension method Any(), creates always as first a new iterator and the tries to get the first element. It is also O(1), but because of creating a new iterator a small amount of memory is allocated for this iterator, each time you call Any(). Inside implementation of MoveNext() which is used by the iterator there are 2 compare operations and one index based access to the list, because MoveNext saves also the current value for the iteration inside a member (see implementation for enumerator of List)
And that's why you should prefer usage of the properties Count or Length if you can use it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

`.Length` iterates through the collection and returns the number of elements. Complexity is `O(n)`

`.Any` checks whether the collection has at least one item. Complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: The Length property is guaranteed to be a O(1) operation when available. Count, on the other hand, depends on the type of collection (it is O(1) for a list).